# Mousemove and keypress not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make an auto-logout on inactivity using JavaScript. The thing is even when I move my mouse and rapidly press any key the timer does not reset.

```
var timeOut;
function reset() {
window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
timeOut = window.setTimeout( "redir()" , 5000 );
}
function redir() {
window.location = "index.php?page=Logout";
}
window.onload = function() { setTimeout("redir()" , 5000 ) };
window.onmousemove = reset;
window.onkeypress = reset;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `timeOut` variable in your `onload` event:

```
window.onload = function() { timeOut = setTimeout("redir()" , 5000 ) };
```

Otherwise, `clearTimeout` can't clear the first timer.

Also note that it's best to refer to the functions directly in `setTimeout()`, like this:

```
window.onload = function() { setTimeout(redir, 5000 ) };
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var timeOut;

function reset() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeOut);
  timeOut = window.setTimeout(redir, 5000);
}

function redir() {
  console.log('redirected');
}

window.onload = function() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(redir, 5000)
}

window.onmousemove = reset;
window.onkeypress = reset;
```